# php domDocument xpath extract links from table

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to use domDocument and xpath to extract the contents of a table including the href attribute of the links which are in some of the cells.  The following code draws a blank.

```
<?php
$url_content='<html>
<body>
<table class="txtable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td><a href="www.example1.com">link 1</a></td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td><a href="www.example2.com">link 2</a></td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($url_content);

$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$rows = $finder->query("//table[@class='txtable']/tbody/tr");

foreach ($rows->childNodes AS $row){
foreach($row->childNodes AS $cell){
    if (($cell->nodeName == "td") OR ($cell->nodeName == "th")){

        echo $cell->nodeValue."<br>";   
    } else {
        echo $cell->getAttribute('href')."<br>";
    }
}
}
```

I fear I am not understanding something basic about xpath or domDocument.  Help appreciated.

I am expecting for $rows to be a collection of rows which I can iterate through using foreach.  The echo statements should show the contents of each .

If the child is not 'td' or 'th', in this case it must be 'a' then I want to echo out the href attribute

I am getting nothing at all in the browser

If I run from php I get

PHP Notice:  Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$childNodes in /var/www/follow/php/domtest.php on line 35
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/follow/php/domtest.php on line 35

Comment: Please always describe what you want to achieve, for example by posting expected output. Also give any warnings and/or error message that occur (and here, they do).

Comment: @Jens See additional details added.  Hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach ($rows->childNodes AS $row){`

should be

`foreach ($rows as $row){`